# Editing exception e to catch letters not decimals

Tags: java, arrays, exception, floating-point, try-catch

I'm writing a program that takes 10 floating point numbers as input. However, whenever I enter a decimal the program sends me an error. I question is: how would I edit my current try-catch exception to catch only letters, etc., and allow decimals to be entered (and then store them into an array). Also, regardless of this problem, my program is also outputting the average many times, and always saying that it is equal to 0.

Below is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Average {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Average().average(new double[10]);
}

public double average(double[] number) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double[] numberList = new double[10]; //array to hold all numbers
    double[] largerList = new double[10]; //array to hold numbers greater than the average


    int numberIndex = 0;
    int largerIndex = 0;



    System.out.printf("Please enter 10 floating-point numberes.\nIf more than 10 values are entered, the numbers following 10 are ignored.\nIf less than 10 numbers are entered, the program will wait for you to enter 10.\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


        try { //try catch exception to catch decimal inputs as well as more /less than 10 integers
            x = scanner.nextInt();
            sum += numberList[x]; //add up all inputs to find sum
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Please reenter 10 integer values.");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            i = -1;
            numberIndex = 0;
            largerIndex = 0;
            numberList = new double[10];
            largerList = new double[10];
            continue;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + number[i];
        double average = sum / number.length;

        //return average;

        if (x > average) {
            largerList[largerIndex] = x; //add negative input to negativeList array
            largerIndex = largerIndex + 1;

        }
        System.out.println("Average value of your input is: " + average);
        System.out.println();

    }



    for (int i = 0; i < largerIndex; i++) {
        System.out.println(largerList[i]);
    }
    return 0;





}
```

}

Comment: You don't specify which values you `catch`, you only specify the type of exception.  If you only want exceptions *thrown* (or not thrown) under certain circumstances you must arrange the code to pre-test as necessary, before the exception might be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the nextInt() function, which only returns ints. Ints cannot hold decimals. Consult the API and take a look at the nextFloat() and nextDouble() methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

For your Average problem, Your print statement is into a for loop so it will be executed `number.length` times. Move the print statements outside the loop. You will also need the declaration of the average variable to be outside the loop. Also you should only need to the loop to calculate the sum, you don't need  the calculate the average everytime

```
double average;
for(/*loop conditions*/)
{
    sum = sum + number[i];
}
average = sum / number.length;
System.out.println("Average value of your input is: " + average);
System.out.println();
```